# Why `wrapper` is better than 'adder'?

Tags: programming-languages

A bone-bare example of decorator is:

```
def strong(func):
    def wrapper():
        return '<strong>' + func() + '</strong>'
    return wrapper
@strong
def greet():
    return 'Hello!'
```

`wrapper` is an entitled name for the 'inside first-order-function' inside the Higher-Order function `strong`.
My question is that the word 'wrapper' has no real meaning except to confuse newbies.
Why not use 'adder',because it can be discerned intuitively

> [Decorator pattern - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)
>   In object-oriented programming, the decorator pattern is a design pattern that allows behavior to be **added** to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class.[1]

The keyword in wikipedia' explanation is 'added'

in [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/decorate)

> to **add** something to an object or place, especially in order to make it more attractive:

The keyword is also 'add'

So why `wrapper` is better than 'adder'?

Comment: Consider `@staticmethod` decorator. It doesn't really add anything, it rather *removes* `self` from argument list.

Comment: Besides, "wrap" has meaning. Just like you can wrap something in paper, you can "wrap" function in another function, where outer functions forms "layer" that encompasses input and output of inner function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because not all wrappers are adders. Some adapt an input to some output. Some remove things (like a wrapper to trim strings, or a security filter on collections).

Comment: "Adder" suggests it is adding something to its input, while as a "Wrapper" is sanitizing / preparing its input. Not to mention "add" suggests math, which many wrappers have nothing to do with.